# Is it possible to use Gmail's spell-check in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

By Gmail's spell-check I refer to the following feature visible in the compose window:

**Screenshots:**

[image: Spell-check 1]

[image: Spell-check 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the feature is present in Inbox, as per this [response on Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/jzoSr-MnwWA).

There are other spell checkers you could use though like [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/).

Answer (score 1):

For Google Inbox, you turn Spell Checking feature on and off with right click of mouse on text area.

Right click on some text and you will see options there.

Comment: this is not google's spell check, it's your browser's.